# String to string replacement in file while taking those string from a file

Tags: bash, shell

I have following requirement to be written in bash, which is as follows

I have file consist of filename,stra,strb,colname
filename: Name of the file
stra: string to be find out
strb: string to be replaced with
colname: is name of the column in file

stringlist.csv:

`filename,stra,strb,colname
x.txt,aaa,xxx,col1
y.txt,bbb,yyy,col1`

x.txt:

`col1,col2,col3
aaa,10,20
bbb,20,30
aaa,21,34
ccc,43,98`

y.txt:

`aaa,10,20
bbb,20,30
aaa,21,34
ccc,43,98`

From the stringlist.csv as input file, In x.txt column col1 aaa should be replaced with xxx and respectively in y.txt col1 containing bbb should be replaced with yyy and other content in the file should remain same

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by myself. I was expecting some hint but not the code

```
echo -n "Enter 1 for directory
         Enter 2 for list of files
         Enter 3 for one file as input: "
read mode
if [ $mode -eq 1 ]; then
        echo -n "Enter direcotry path: "
        read dir
        DIRS=`ls -l $dir  | awk '{print $9}'`
        echo -n "Do you want to override the file or want to create a new file(y/n)? "
        read choice
        if [ $choice == "n" ]; then
                echo -n "Enter the prefix of the output file. Output file will be prefix followed by filename: "
                        read prefix
        elif [ $choice == "y" ]; then
                :
        else
                echo  $'You have chosen invalid option.... Bye!!\n'
                exit
        fi
elif [ $mode -eq 2 ]; then
        echo -n "Enter List of files separated by space: "
        read DIRS
        echo -n "Do you want to override the file or want to create a new file(y/n)? "
        read choice
        if [ $choice == "n" ]; then
                echo -n "Enter the prefix of the output file. Output file will be prefix followed by filename: "
                        read prefix
        elif [ $choice == "y" ]; then
                :
        else
                echo  $'You have chosen invalid option.... Bye!!\n'
                exit
        fi
elif [ $mode -eq 3 ]; then
        echo -n "Enter file name: "
        read DIRS
        echo -n "Do you want to override the file or want to create a new file(y/n)? "
        read choice
        if [ $choice == "n" ]; then
                echo -n "Enter the prefix of the output file. Output file will be prefix followed by filename: "
                        read prefix
        elif [ $choice == "y" ]; then
                :
        else
                echo  $'You have chosen invalid option.... Bye!!\n'
                exit
        fi
else
        echo  $'You have chosen invalid option.... Bye!!\n'
        exit
fi
echo -n "Enter file delimiter: "
read del
echo -n "enter string replacement file: "
read strrepfile
echo -n "Enter Delimiter for string replacement input file: "
read indel
if [ $indel == "tab" ]; then
        indel='\t'
        sed "s/$indel/|/g" $strrepfile > $strrepfile.1
else
         sed "s/$indel/|/g" $strrepfile > $strrepfile.1
fi
#filenames=`awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS='$indel1'}{print $1}' $strrepfile`
if [ $del == "tab" ]; then
        del1='"'"\t"'"'
else
        del1='"'$del'"'
fi
for var in $DIRS; do
        if [ $mode -eq 1 ]; then
                colheadfile=$dir/$var
        else
                colheadfile=$var
        fi
        break
done
awvar="-v col"
while read -r line
do
        echo "$line" > temp
        stra=`awk -F '|' '{print $1}' temp`
        strb=`awk -F '|' '{print $2}' temp`
        col=`awk -F '|' '{print $3}' temp`
        if [ $del == "tab" ]; then
                del='\t'
        fi
        filedel="'"$del"'"
        colpos=`head -1 $colheadfile | tr -s $filedel '\n' | nl -nln |  grep $col | cut -f1`
        colpos=$(echo $colpos | tr -d ' ')
        awkvar1=$awkvar1$awvar$colpos'='$colpos' '
        gsubvar=$gsubvar'gsub("'$stra'","'$strb'",$'$colpos');'
done < "$strrepfile.1"
echo $awkvar1
echo $gsubvar
for dir1 in $DIRS; do
        echo $dir1
        if [ $mode -eq 1 ] && [ $choice == "y" ]; then
                awk $awkvar1 'BEGIN{FS=OFS='$del1'}{'$gsubvar'print;}' $dir/$dir1 > $dir1
        elif [ $mode -eq 1 ] && [ $choice == "n" ]; then
                awk $awkvar1 'BEGIN{FS=OFS='$del1'}{'$gsubvar'print;}' $dir/$dir1 > $prefix'_'$dir1
        elif [ $mode -eq 2 ] && [ $choice == "y" ]; then
                awk $awkvar1 'BEGIN{FS=OFS='$del1'}{'$gsubvar'print;}' $dir1 > $dir1
        elif [ $mode -eq 2 ] && [ $choice == "n" ]; then
                awk $awkvar1 'BEGIN{FS=OFS='$del1'}{'$gsubvar'print;}' $dir1 > $prefix'_'$dir1
        elif [ $mode -eq 3 ] && [ $choice == "y" ]; then
                awk $awkvar1 'BEGIN{FS=OFS='$del1'}{'$gsubvar'print;}' $dir1 > $dir1
        elif [ $mode -eq 3 ] && [ $choice == "n" ]; then
                awk $awkvar1 'BEGIN{FS=OFS='$del1'}{'$gsubvar'print;}' $dir1 > $prefix'_'$dir1
        fi
done
rm $strrepfile.1
rm temp
```

Thanks

Comment: actually my requirement slightly go changed and I completed. Stringlist.csv file doesnot have the first column with filenames. it will have only three columns i.e., stra, strb and columnname. To this code we can pass directory (assuming all files are in same format) or multiple files (assuming all files are in same format) or single file.